# ios button doesn't tap - noob issue

Tags: ios, xcode

So I'm a new ios developer and am working on my first app.  I have a 3d game in unity that I exported as an xcode project and my goal is to add an ios menu before accessing the game.  Suffice it to say, I'm struggling with this.  I've watch some of the stanford tutorials (great!), and read some tutorials I thought was applicable, but I'm stuck.  Here's what I've got:

I hijacked the main.m file to load myAppDelegate (instead of the one Unity made).  myAppDelegate then loads an instance of myViewController and adds it as a subview to the window.  In the myViewController, I have:

```
-(IBAction) displayView:(id) sender{
 UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] 
 initWithTitle:@"Button Pressed" 
 message:@"You have pressed the Button view."
 delegate:nil
 cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" 
 otherButtonTitles:nil];
 [alert show];
 [alert release];   
}
```

I'm just trying to issue an alert on a button click.  I have the function defined in the .h file with `-(IBAction) displayView:(id) sender;`

On the view side of things, I added an entry to my plist file I have Main Nib File Base Name set to MainWindow.

Then in the Interface Builder, in MainWindow.xib, I had added from the Library, myAppDelegate and myViewController.  For myAppDelegate, I added myViewController as the viewController delegate, window is Window, and the reference outlet is the file owner.  For myViewController, the referencing outlet is the myAppDelegate. (To be honest, this part confuses me. It doesn't have much of a corollary to my php web app background.)

In myViewController.xib, the File Owner is myViewController.  Received action shows a link from my function (displayView) to a button.  Then for the view, I opened that up, painted it red and littered it with general ios widgets (buttons, datepickers, etc).  I hooked up one of the buttons to have a touch up inside of displayView.

So that's all that I've done, I load up the app on my device and I see exactly what I laid out on view.  But nothing is intractable.  I expect taping my button to show the alert defined above.  But that doesn't happen.  In fact nothing happens. So I suspect the hooking of all of this up is incorrect.  But the button doesn't even depress? I would expect the white button to flash blue (down state) when I tap it.  Further, I would expect the date picker (not hooked up to function), to spin as I interact with it.

It's as if my touches aren't getting sent to the view.  Does anybody have any idea what I might be doing wrong? Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: i think you have several problems here, but one of them is that an alert view needs a delegate, because that delegate must have the button pressed method. (check the uialertview protocol).

Comment: Make sure the UIButton in your xib file is connected to the IBAction in your view controller using the TouchUpInside action.

Comment: I think I already have that in there.  Right clicking on the UIButton in the xib shows for the TouchUpInside has linked "File's Owner: displayView".  That should already do what you're saying, right?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
-(IBAction) displayView:(id) sender{

UIAlertView * myAlert;

myAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Button Pressed" 
  message:@"You have pressed the Button view."
  delegate:nil
  cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" 
  otherButtonTitles:nil];

 [myAlert show]; 
 /* And make sure to have this action connected to your button in xib           
 file */

}
```